# How to update/edit the user profile information in asp.net identity EF code first approach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, identity

I've added some properties to my application user class just as below:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

And I have added those properties accordingly in `RegisterViewModel` and updated the `Register` view accordingly. Everything is functioning super fine and I can add users with those custom properties added.
The question is how can I update/edit the user profile data including (Name, LastName, DOB and etc) after the user created the account.
I know I have to have an `ActionResult` method for this but frankly I don't know much about it.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Within an action method simply use your data context to retrieve, update and/or save models.

```
using (var ctx = new MyDataContext())
{
   var person = ctx.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault();
   person.Name = "Johnny";
   person.LastName = "Depp";

   ctx.SaveChanges();                
}
```